# 2016 Nissan Versa SV flywheel

Tags: cvt-transmission, flywheel, shifter

Is the flywheel on a 2016 Nissan Versa SV part of the transmission? Is the gear shifter part of the transmission? Is it common for these parts to be excluded from the warranty on the transmission?

Comment: Welcome to Mechanics stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Your vehicle would typically have multiple warranties. Two key warranties:  One for “bumper to bumper” and another for “powertrain”.

Bumper to bumper warranty, also called “Basic”, is 3 yr or 36,000 miles on odometer, whichever comes first.

The Powertrain warranty is 5 yrs or 60,000 miles.

Your warranty details are [here](https://owners.nissanusa.com/content/techpub/common/2016/2016-nissan-warranty-booklet.pdf)

And there are lots of different pieces to the entire warranty coverage: emmissions, corrosion, battery, tires, etc.

Note, the flywheel is attached to and part of the engine. This part is covered by your 5yr/ 60,000 miles Powertrain coverage.

The powertrain warranty includes Engine, Transmission and Transaxle, Drivetrain, and Restraint System, supplied  by Nissan subject to the exclusions listed under the heading “WHAT IS NOT COVERED. Other driveline parts as indicated in warranty details.

From what I can see of that warranty guide, the transmission gear shifter and linkages are NOT covered by the powertrain warranty. They are covered by 3 years / 36,000 mile basic coverage. Check page 6 for Transmission and Transaxle for details here. Its pretty clear only internal transmission parts are covered under Powertrain warranty. And yup, shifter and linkages are external parts.

Comment: Don't assume the dealer knows the warranty details!  I once had a Ford Thunderbird with a turbocharger that failed.  The dealer said that the turbo was not covered and that would have been an expensive repair bill.  I had read the warranty and it specifically said "turbochargers and related components - 5 years or 50000 miles".  Once I pointed that out the dealer started mumbling and said they would cover it.

Comment: @jwh20 it's also possible the dealer did know, but hoped you didn't.